# Deleting a file on the NAS says "delete immediately" but it is still on the NAS's recycle bin?

Tags: nas, trash

I have a WD NAS, and sometimes I right click a file and choose "Move to Trash", a box pops up saying the file will be deleted immediately (and cannot be undone).  So I thought I released the space.

But later on, I found that the NAS actually has a folder called "Recycle Bin," and the deleted files are still there.  So, it looks like the space  is actually not released, and I have to find the Recycle Bin on different volumes and then delete the files.

That is kind of manual and low level and is hard to manage.  Is there a way to do it in the Dashboard or configure it so that it really is "delete immediately"?

P.S. I just found, what's more, if I move some files between Shares in the same NAS -- note that it is "moving", then the NAS actually decrease in storage, and I found the file in the Recycle Bin... so it is like a copy and delete. This makes it even harder to manage.

P.S. I found out Recycle Bin seems to be on a "per share" level, meaning each share can be configured to have a recycle bin or not.  If there is no recycle bin, then the file is immediately deleted and space released.

Answer (score 1):

This is not new and many NAS boxes have this feature.  It's just a method to provide for recovery, in addition to backup.

> I have to find the Recycle Bin on different volumes and then delete the files? That is kind of manual and low level and is hard to manage. Is there a way to do it in the Dashboard or configure it so that it really is "delete immediately"?

From your Apple (SMB) *client*?  No.  This is no more different that connecting to a friends MacBook via a shared folder and deleting a file.  You would have no access to empty their trash.

Why?  Because the inherent property of a NAS is sharing and usually by more than one person.  For instance, if we both deleted files from a NAS and you realized you needed it back, you wouldn't appreciate me emptying the trash of *your* things.

However, emptying of the Trash doesn't have to be a manual process.  FreeNAS, and my Synology NAS both have a feature for both manually emptying the trash as well as setting up a schedule to do so.  Here's a screen grab from my personal Synology:

[image: Synology Recycle Bin Control Panel]

Check your NAS documentation to see if you can set a schedule for when the trash gets emptied.

> What's more, if I move some files between Shares in the same NAS -- note that it is "moving", then the NAS actually decrease in storage, and I found the file in the Recycle Bin... so it is like a copy and delete. This makes it even harder to manage.

Yes, especially so if you're doing it from an SMB client like your MacBook.  A move is, in fact, a copy and delete.  This is not a fault of of the OS - macOS on your client and Linux (likely) on the NAS.  It's just a reality of [SAMBA](https://www.samba.org/).

While I absolutely love my NAS for the convenience it brings, I try not to do any massive file operations from my client device.  Instead I will log in either via the web interface or via SSH so that a move (`mv` is actually a move and not a copy/delete).  In effect, I bypass SAMBA for these operations.

Comment: it can make sense... please also see something I found out later in the last PS: "P.S. I found out Recycle Bin seems to be on a 'per share' level, meaning each share can be configured to have a recycle bin or not.  If there is no recycle bin, then the file is immediately deleted and space released."

Comment: Correct.  If I turn off the Recycle bin on a share on my NAS, the same thing happens, the file is deleted immediately.  The thing is macOS has no idea if there is a Trash bin so the message you see on macOS is telling you that if you delete it, it's not going into macOS's Trash bin.

Comment: ok... I guess it is like an abstraction black box... macOS tells NAS to "delete it", and there is no protocol that the deleting side tells the caller whether they are providing a recycle bin. And the "delete" action is just taken, and the NAS will "delete it immediately" or "move to recycle bin" depending on whether there is a recycle bin on that share. But from macOS to NAS, it is a simple "message" (as in OOP), "delete foo.txt".

Comment: I guess it could be architected so that "delete foo.txt" will return a message to the caller, saying "it is deleted but note that I have a recycle bin" and macOS can echo that (file deleted but it is on their recycle bin), but it is just not done that way.